# Kubernetes : How to ensure one pod gets scheduled on each worker node?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

**Goal :** Have one pod (namely 'log-scraper') get scheduled on every node at least once but no more than once

**Assume a cluster has the following nodes**

Nodes

1. master/control-plane
2. worker-1
3. worker-2
4. worker-2

**Pod I'm working with**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: log-scraper
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: container-log-dir
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/containers
  containers:
    - image: "logScraper:latest"
      name: log-munger
      volumeMounts:
      - name: container-log-dir
        mountPath: /var/log/logging-app
```

Adding affinity to select only 'worker' nodes (or non-mater nodes)

```
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
            - key: "worker"
              operator: In
              values:
              - "true"
```

**Question 1:** How do I ensure every `node` runs **ONE-AND-ONLY-ONE** `pod` of type `log-scraper`

**Question 2:** What other manifests should be applied/added to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Concept

There are two important things when it comes to assigning Pods to Nodes - **"Affinity"** and **"AntiAffinity"**.

- Affinity will basically select based on given criteria while anti-affinity will avoid based on given criteria.
- With Affinity and Anti-affinity, you can use operators like `In`, `NotIn`, `Exist`, `DoesNotExist`, `Gt` and `Lt`. When you use `NotIn` and `DoesNotExist`, then it becomes anti-affinity.

Now, in Affinity/Antiaffinity, you have 2 choices - Node affinity/antiaffinity and Inter-pod affinity/antiaffinity

#### Node affinity/antiaffinity

Node affinity is conceptually similar to nodeSelector -- it allows you to constrain which nodes your pod is eligible to be scheduled on, based on labels on the node.

#### Inter-pod affinity/antiaffinity

Inter-pod affinity and anti-affinity allow you to constrain which nodes your pod is eligible to be scheduled based on labels on pods that are already running on the node rather than based on labels on nodes.

## Your Solution

Basically what you need is "Antiaffinity" and in that "Pod antiaffinity" instead of Node. So, your solution should look something like below (please note that since I do not have 3 Node cluster so I couldn't test this, so thin chances that you might have to do minor code adjustment):

```
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        labelSelector:
          - matchExpressions:
            - key: worker
              operator: In
              values:
              - log-scraper
```

---

Read more over [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity), and especially go through example over [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#always-co-located-in-the-same-node).

Answer (score 8):

You should probably use [Daemonsets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) which are exactly made for this purpose of scheduling one pod per node and gets automatically added to new nodes in case of cluster autoscaling.

Comment: It looks you are trying to write a custom logging system with the above concept of affinity and Daemonsets provided the best use case for logging. See the [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#create-a-daemonset) used for configuring fluentd as daemonsets for providing the logging to the cluster.

Comment: Exactly. Use the right abstraction (daemonset in this case) for the right problem and don't try to just hack something together using lower level primitives (ie: pods)

Answer (score 1):

## Using Pod Topology Spread Constraints

Another way to do it is using **Pod Topology Spread Constraints**.

You will set up taints and tolerances as usual to control on which nodes the pods can be scheduled. Then add some labels to the pod. I will use the pod label `id: foo-bar` in the example. Then to allow only a single pod from a `replicaSet`, `deployment` or other to be scheduled per node add following in the pod spec.

```yaml
topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        id: foo-bar
```

`topologyKey` is the label of nodes. The `kubernetes.io/hostname` is a [default label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#kubernetesiohostname) set per node. Put pod labels inside `matchLabels`. Create the resources and kubescheduler should schedule a single pod with the matching labels per node.

To learn more, check out the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/) and also this [excellent blog post](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/introducing-podtopologyspread/).