# podantiaffinity & scheduler

Tags: kubernetes

I want to try to have only one webserver per node, and if one webserver my autoscaler will add a new node but the scheduler seems to doesn't care about my `podAntiAffinity` rule. I think it's because of my "webserver-*". As the value can be random (it's a generated id so webserver-id)

```yaml
tolerations:
  - key: "webserver-dedicated"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
affinity:
  podAntiAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: app
          operator: In
          values: 
          - webserver-*
      topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
  nodeAffinity: 
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: 
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: role 
          operator: In 
          values:
          - webserver
```

That's what i've tried and i really don't understand why my podantiaffinity rule doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes : How to ensure one pod gets scheduled on each worker node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66402138/kubernetes-how-to-ensure-one-pod-gets-scheduled-on-each-worker-node)

Comment: Not really, i want to understand : Why two pod with label app=webserver are in same node, with the good toleration. Why the autoscaler didn't triggered a new node in this node pool with the good taints as i have a toleration and a node pool